# How can I get "52:178/179 'XXX BBB'" by using regexp?

Tags: regex, tcl

A text file like below:

```
1:1/1988 'XX'
1:2/1988 'BB'
...
1:1987/1988 'Target1'
1:1988/1988 'XXX'
2:1/1785 'XDS'
...
2:1784/1785 'Target2'
...
```

How can I get **Target1** and **Target2** by using regexp in tcl?
Thanks a lot.

Sorry guys, I think you are misunderstanding my question.

My point is \d+:**n-1**/**n** 'Target'.

Is there any ways to get this?

I using this to get Targets.

`if {[regexp {\d+:(\d+)/(\d+) +'(\w+)'} $str vv Num1 Num2 Target] } {
     if {[expr $Num2 - $Num1]==1} {
        GET TARGET...
    }
 }`

I just want to know if there any smart way to get Target???

Thanks again.

Comment: Do you want to get `**Target1**` or `Target1`?

Answer (score 1):

To escape `asterisk(*)` in TCL, you need `\\`

To extract substring from string you need `group capturing` which is `(.*)` in regexp

Try this,

```
;# For example
set var "1:1987/1988 '**Target1**'"
regexp ".* \'\\*\\*(.*)\\*\\*\'" $var match match1 
puts $match1 ;# Gives Output Target1
```

To extract `substring` from whole file,

```
set fd [open "filename.txt" r]
while {[gets $fd line] >= 0} {
    if {[regexp ".* \'\\*\\*(.*)\\*\\*\'" $line match match1]} {
        puts $match1
    }
}
```

Documentation: [regexp](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986), [group-capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tcl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using pattern grouping:

```
\*\*([^*]+)\*\*
```

Or using lookarounds:

```
(?<=\*\*)[^*]+(?=\*\*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hE7wU7/3)